# 4 arguments? 3?

Tags: c, parameters, arguments

I was studying some questions from a C programming book and encountered an interesting question:

1. True or false?

   The statement:

   ```
   scanf("%d:%f:%1f\n", &a, &b, &c);
   ```

   contains four arguments `"%d:%f:%1f\n"`, `&a`, `&b` and `&c`.

   The given answer was **true**. Why is this so? I don't see 4 arguments / parameter here.
2. True or false?

   The statement:

   ```
   printf("%+2d",123);
   ```

   display `+12`

   The answer was **false**. Why is this so?

Comment: Regarding #1: how many arguments do you see (I count four)? Regarding #2: what would you expect - did you try it?

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Please consider editing your question such that you use the formatting features. Code is usually marked with backticks resulting in something like `this`. Also I suppose that the missing fourth `"` in your first question is accidental, due to your copying.

Comment: Then please only ask one question at a time. In the present case you might have learned from the answer to the first, to completely avoid the second since you'd know where to look for it.

Answer (score 6):

First;

```
scanf("%d:%f:%1f\n", &a, &b, &c);
```

contains 4 arguments;

```
1: "%d:%f:%1f\n"
2: &a
3: &b
4: &c
```

Second;

```
printf("%+2d",123);
```

2 indicates *minimum field width*, but 123 is wider than 2 characters and will be printed in full. The `+` forces a sign, so the result is `+123`.

Answer (score 5):

**Question #1**

Arguments are those separated by commas :).

```
scanf("%d:%f:%1f\n", &a, &b, &c);
   // 1              2   3   4
```

**Question #2**

The line prints +123, try it.

```
printf("%+2d",123);
```

From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/:

Synopsis: `%[flags][width][.precision][length]specifier`

- Flag (`+`): Forces to precede the result with a plus or minus sign (+ or -) even for positive numbers. By default, only negative numbers are preceded with a - sign.
- Width (`2`): Minimum number of characters to be printed. If the value to be printed is shorter than this number, the result is padded with blank spaces. The value is not truncated even if the result is larger.
- Specifier (`d`): Signed decimal integer

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, arguments means parameters passed to the function, not format statement parameters. In the second question, the plus says output a plus and the 2 says use at least two places for the output. Prints will not truncate a number, so it will print out all three digits.

Answer (score 1):

First argument:    `"%d:%f:%1f\n"`

Second argument:    `&a`

Third argument:     `&b`

Fourth argument:    `&c`

There are four arguments passed to the function in the function call.